# WordPress / FB Sharing: How to fix invalid image content type error?

Tags: wordpress, facebook-graph-api, facebook-debugger

I want to show the featured image of a post when I share it in Facebook, for that, I used [All in One SEO](https://wordpress.org/plugins/all-in-one-seo-pack/) plugin.

The problem is that the image of the article doesn't show when I debug it on Facebook Debugger.

The `property="og:image" :HyYouD3yGwImxH8EHcDoC8lTzQwsp5lly1Htr8ui-1.jpeg` is showing in the browser as [scraped][3], but I don't understand why I have this error:

> Provided og:image URL,
> `HyYouD3yGwImxH8EHcDoC8lTzQwsp5lly1Htr8ui-1.jpeg`
> could not be processed as an image because it has an invalid content
> type.

Can you help me to solve this problem?

Comment: it does not even work in the browser (error 404), so of course it does not work as og:image. maybe it works for you in your network or with some ip redirection, who knows...but it does not work for me. it must be public.

Comment: it works in my home http://www.screencast.com/t/7a5NWl7GRhQ

Comment: how can i fix that ?

Comment: check your .htaccess file, for example. plenty of google results for this: https://fancythemes.com/fix-image-upload-issue-wordpress/

Comment: thank you i solved the problem

Comment: why not create an answer about it then, and accept it?

Comment: @jackjohn what was the solution?